# Value on the scale of Virtue

Tags: single-word-requests

How can I say "the value some action has by having or not having the quality of virtue"? I want to say "virtual value" but that sounds like the value is not real. How else can I phrase this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Virtuous*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/virtuous) means possessing virtue; having or showing virtue.

You could say *virtuous value* or that the action was *virtuous*.

Another option is to choose [a synonym for virtuous](http://thesaurus.com/browse/virtuous), and say something like *noble value*.

Answer (score 1):

**Moral Value**

"His action was commended for its moral value." Virtue and morality aren't exactly the same thing, but they are similar enough to make this work in mosts contexts.

Answer (score 0):

**Virtue value** is an option, at least better than "virtual value". But there may be better ways still to say it, including dropping the word "value".

Answer (score 0):

Lexically speaking the word OP seeks should be *virtuousness*, but in practice [most people](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=righteousness%20of%20his%20action,virtuousness%20of%20his%20action&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) would use the near-synonym ***righteousness*** in this context...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In D&D games, this quantity was called 'karma points'. The phrase seems to be making a comeback:[Ngram for karma points](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=karma%20points&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: *Virtue* and *karma* are reasonably close in a D&D session, but in the real world the differences are significant.

Comment: I thought perhaps AA was looking for the units with which virtue might be measured, something similar to 'pleasure utils', from the field of economics. I would say that 'karma points' conveys that.